# Adding the DUMMIFIED columns to ORIGINAL DATASET in R

Tags: r, cbind

I am trying to create the dummy variables for my dataset and add the new dummy variable columns to the dataset. However, on doing this the name of the new columns is coming as the address of R folder. How can i directly add the columns with my desired naming convention. TIA.

```
dataset= read.csv("student-mat.csv")
library(dummies)
dataset =cbind(dataset,dummy(dataset$address))
print(dataset)
```

[Dataset Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0yB3.png)

[Image of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBq9y.png)

Comment: Please add the first columns of your dataset for us to run code with.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your CSV file. Can you post the structure of the file? Random Guess - Try with `dummy(as.character(dataset$address))`

Comment: The dummy columns are getting created properly with the code that i have pasted. Issue is while adding those columns to the dataset. It is taking some weird name for those columns.

Comment: I have updated the image link, it has the structure of the file as well.